# How to import deep_sort module in google colab?

Tags: object-detection, object-detection-api

**I try to import the deep_srort module in my colab. But it shows me the following:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b784ee656306> in <module>()
----> 1 from deep_sort import preprocessing
      2 from deep_sort import nn_matching
      3 from deep_sort.detection import Detection
      4 from deep_sort.tracker import Tracker
      5 from tools import generate_detections as gdet

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deep_sort'
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloning the repo and installing the requirements solved the problem for me:

```
!git clone https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort
%cd yolov4-deepsort/
!pip install -r requirements-gpu.txt
```